# Cannot link libsqlite3.so in gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, sqlite

I'm trying to compile the following program with gcc 4.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.1
with the package `libsqlite3-dev` installed:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sqlite3 *s3;
    char *filename = ":memory:";
    sqlite3_open(filename, &s3);
    return 0;
}
```

When running `gcc -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lsqlite3 program.c` I get
the error:

```
/tmp/ccjvJqkW.o: In function `main':
program.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It looks to me like I have the correct library installed:

```
autobound@Calcium:~$ locate libsqlite3.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6

autobound@Calcium:~$ readelf -a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so | grep sqlite3_open
    71: 00000000000947b0     5 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 sqlite3_open_v2
   157: 00000000000947a0    12 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 sqlite3_open
   194: 00000000000947c0   181 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 sqlite3_open16
```

Running clang with the same arguments (`clang -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lsqlite3 program.c`)
builds the executable just fine.  In fact, the `-L` argument isn't even
needed for clang to build it.

The verbose output of gcc is:

```
autobound@Calcium:~/src/c/sqlitetest (master)$ gcc --verbose -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lsqlite3 program.c
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu program.c -quiet -dumpbase program.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase program -version -fstack-protector -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccIBEqw6.s
GNU C (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) version 4.8.2 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.8.2, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) version 4.8.2 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.8.2, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: dc75e0628c9356affcec059d0c81cc01
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/cca2r2gq.o /tmp/ccIBEqw6.s
GNU assembler version 2.24 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/collect2 --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. -lsqlite3 /tmp/cca2r2gq.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/tmp/cca2r2gq.o: In function `main':
program.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change order of parameters

```
gcc program.c -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lsqlite3
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked!  I didn't know the order mattered.  All I can find about that in the man page is that _Also, the placement of the -l option is significant._ with no further explanation.